# How to restrict what like will do

Tags: powershell

I made a function for learning.  The function works as intended.
I would like to do better with this bit of the code `$_.displayroot -like "*$NameToMap*"`.

Currently using my function and `-NameToMap` with any part of a mapped drive the letter will return.
The issue is what if more then one drive is mapped or if two similar drives are mapped.
How can I make the `-like` more exclusive if possible?

```
function FindADriveLetter {
    [alias("FADL")]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $False)][string]$NameToMap
    )

    <# ver 1.0  Author Dan Casmas 9/2021. Designed to work on Windows OS.
    Has only been tested with 5.1 and 7 PS Versions. Requires a minimum of PS 5.1 .#>
    #Requires -Version 5.1

    $Letter = $null
    function FreeLetter {
        #this $Letter bit of code below is curtosy of https://stackoverflow.com/
        $Letter =
        try {
            $null = Get-PSDrive -ErrorAction Stop -Name ([char[]] 'efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        }
        catch {
            $_.TargetObject
        }
        
        if (-not $Letter) {
            Write-Warning "No drive letters available."
            Return $null 
        }

        Return [string]$Letter        
    }

    If ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($NameToMap)) {
        $Letter = FreeLetter
    }
    Else {
        $Letter = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object name, displayroot -ExpandProperty name | Where-Object { $_.displayroot -like "*$NameToMap*" } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError

        If ($ProcessError -or $null -eq $Letter) {
            $Letter = FreeLetter
        }
    }

    Return [string]$Letter
}
```

Comment: I am thinking maybe I could make the ‘nametomap’ parameter require a minimum of 3 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` it only outputs the values of whatever that property is.  In your case, you are only sending the name values to the `Where-Object` cmdlet, no displayroot.  Completely remove that Select-Object part - its not needed there.  Move it to the end and here use -expandproperty to only output the Name (drive letter) values.  Also here, you may have to consider what to do if your $NameToMap matches more than 1 drive and outputs more than one drive letter.  I'll leave that exercise for you.

Change

```
$Letter = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | 
    Select-Object name, displayroot -ExpandProperty name | 
        Where-Object { $_.displayroot -like "*$NameToMap*" } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError
```

to

```
$Letter = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError |  
    Where-Object { $_.displayroot -like "*$NameToMap*" } | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Helpful and informative. I been thinking how I can a test for more then 1. @daniel think I should change to ‘’‘??$NameToMap?’’’’

Comment: What is the goal of your function?  How it seems to me is that you are trying to return the letter of an existing mapped drive that matches your filter OR return the first unused drive letter if there is no match.   How would you use this?  To me it would be confusing to provide a filter ($NameToMap) and get back a drive letter when there actually isn't a drive mapped matching my filter.  If I didn't know better I would assume that the letter returned is the drive letter of what I'm looking for and the drive is mapped, but it could instead be just a free unused drive letter?

Comment: The point is I end up drive mapping a lot and wanted to find a free drive letter or find if a drive was already mapped. That was how this started and for learning

Comment: I definitely commend you on the function and learning.  Part of learning how to create functions is also defining a clear purpose for a function.  I'm just pointing out that it is a bit unclear.  If I provide a $NameToMap I would expect that it will only return mapped drives that match my term or nothing because I may then want to do something with that drive letter like run an application @ $letter:\app\app.exe but if I'm returned some unused drive letter this would not work.  Just something to think about.

Comment: Regarding, your question about testing for more than 1, the code above will already return all drive letters where `$_.displayroot -like "*$NameToMap*"` which depending on the drives mapped and your $NameToMap value could be more than one.  $Letter then would be an array of drive letters.  At the end of your function you `return [string]$letter` which would convert your array of letters into a single string which would be strange.  Example `$letters =@('A','B','C'); [string]$letters` will return the string `A B C`.  Typically in PS functions we do not use `Return`, just the value `$letter`